# Serving a asmx request on dot net core

Tags: c#, web-services, asp.net-core, madcap

I'm trying to create a small website to host the output from MadCap Flare using ASP .Net Core (1.1). The MadCap Flare project uses an asmx service to provide some server side search functionality. Everything runs fine locally (i.e. starting chrome and navigating to MadCap Flare content).

However, when I try to access the MadCap pages via Kestrel, I start getting 404's while trying to serve requests containing the asmx service e.g.

```
Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:48784/Documentation/[ProductName]/Service/Service.asmx/GetSubsystems
dbug: The request path /Documentation/[ProductName]/Service/Service.asmx/GetSubsystems does not match a supported file type
```

Any thoughts or suggestions on how to tackle this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to open the port 48784 through the firewall, then use the actual IP of the machine that is running instead of localhost.